# Why does a sticky nav change width when it 'sticks'?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints

I have created a sticky nav using way points. The nav is nested inside the header which sits inside a wrapper. If the nav is set to `width:100%` ie the full width of the wrapper, its width becomes 100% of the body when the waypoint is hit and the `position:fixed`.

Is there a way for a sticky nav to have a percentage width?

Comment: Specify a width on the wrapper. Then the `nav` will be 100% of whatever that is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved my own question.

The nav was set to 100% of the wrapper which was 80% of the body. As setting the nav `position:fixed;` takes it out of the flow, changing the width of the nav to be a percentage of the body width (80%) resolves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer. :-)